# Visual Studio publish to azure existing apps error

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, publish

Getting this error when I select a "publish target" in VS 2015 update 3. Had a look for a while online but didn't see anything, so any help would be appreciated if you could point me in the right direction.

```
An error has occurred while processing the request: Method 'StopRemoteProfiler' in type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.WindowsAzure.AzureWebSite' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.WindowsAzure.Impl, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' does not have implementation
```

[image: screenshot]

I updated to the to Azure sdk 2.9.6 last night because of a different issue but related where there was no error, but no existing apps were listed.

I can confirm that this works on my work computer and I have existing apps on Azure, but not working on my home computer.

I am a bit loath to uninstall and reinstall VS, so any help would be appreciated. Of course, if the only solution is to reset, then so be it.

Thanks,
Jarrod

Comment: try to downgrade sdk?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. This is what worked for me.

I updated the "Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.1 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2" by going to Menu -> Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Updates -> Visual Studio Gallery. It shows all the available updates for your version of studio. Select the component to update. It should download a file named "DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3.exe" or something similar. When you run this file, if you have the software already installed then select the repair option. It will ask you to close any running instances of Visual Studio, also make sure you have internet connection.

Also if you are using Web Deploy to publish your app make sure you have Microsoft Web Deploy v3 or higher installed or you will get error. You can do it using Microsoft Web Platform  Installer.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Unfortunately I have a bunch of other problems  

- core tools installer needed privileges for a config folder that didn't exist
- created folder and took ownership
- core installer couldn't open xml file microsoft.visualstudio.offline.config   (file doesn't exist. I am online)
- uninstall/reinstall core tools - same issue
- Uninstalled/reinstalled VS 2015 pro with update 3 - error about  "Microsoft Nuget - package failed"  
- core tools same error
  
Latest version of web deploy  
  
Any assistance, reinstall or otherwise I am willing to listen