# 'StopRemoteProfiler'-error during deployment to Azure

Tags: azure, web-deployment

Trying to deploy very simple webapp to azure, getting this error message, after Ive selected my (MSDN) subscription and VS is about to list

[image: see image]

> Method 'StopRemoteProfiler' in type
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.WindowsAzure.AzureWebSite' from assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.WindowsAzure.Impl, Version=14.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' does not have an
>   implementation.

Any help appreciated...

Comment: did u already check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42315802/visual-studio-publish-to-azure-existing-apps-error

Comment: Nope, didnt work. Did all updates and downloaded the file, ran it and now I dont event have an azure-option during deployment

Answer (score 0):

Installed latest [Azure SDK Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/webpi.ashx/getinstaller/VWDOrVs2015AzurePack.appids) and after that it all worked again